# how to make web search in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Hi i am a student doing my academic project.I need some guidance in completing my project.

My project is based on grails framework which searches for books from 3 different bookstores and gives d price from all the 3 stores.I need help in searching part. 
how to direct the search for those bookstores once user types for required book.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more details. By searching bookstores, do you mean searching in a database or are these like Amazon etc?

Comment: ya it should search from bookstores like amazon,flipkart,infibeam and retrive the prices for searched books.

Comment: Most of them have clearly defined APIs. Although I'm not sure if flipkart has one. But Amazon should. Google for it. If a site doesn't then you'll have to use a crawler like Apache Nutch to fetch and parse the HTML content and extract the data from there. Since you'll know the html structure you're parsing, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: If you find APIs for all the sites you intend to search, then you can do it WHEN the user presses the search button on your page. This will be in an action in a controller. However, if you don't have APIs from all the sites, then you need to run a separate JOB and crawl those sites and index the data. Google for what these terms exactly mean. so, when your user searches, he will be returned data from the index and not an API call.

Answer (score 0):

I would find out if these online bookstores have APIs, or if you have a choice, select the online bookstores **that do** have APIs that you can use to do your searching. For example, Amazon has a "Product Advertising API" that can be used to perform searching of its catalogue (see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG). You usually have to register as an affiliate to get access these sort of things.

Once you have several online bookstores that are accessible via APIs, it is relatively easy to write some grails code to call them, and coordinate the results. APIs usually take the form of Web requests, either REST or SOAP (e.g. see [Amazon - AnatomyOfaRESTRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AnatomyOfaRESTRequest.html)). Groovy's HTTPBuilder can be used to call and consume the bookstores' API web services if you can use simple REST, or I believe there are a couple of Grails plugins (e.g. [REST Client builder](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder)). For SOAP, consider the [Grails CXF Client](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf-client) Grails plugin.

You could do the searches on the APIs one by one, or if you want to get more advanced, you could try calling all 3 APIs at the same time asynchronously using the new servlet 3.0 async feature (see how to use from Grails 2.0.x: [Grails Web Features](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures) - scroll to "Servlet 3.0 Async Features"). You would probably need to coordinate this via the DB, and perhaps poll through AJAX on your result page to check when results come in.

So the sequence would be as follows:

1. User submits search request from a form on a page to the server
2. Server creates and saves a DB object to track requests, kicks off API calls asynchronously (i.e. so the request is not blocked), then returns a page back to the user.
3. The "pending results" page is shown to user and a periodic AJAX update is used to check the progress of results.
4. Meanwhile your API calls are executing. When they return, hopefully with results, they update the DB object (or better, a related object) to store the results and status of the call.
5. Eventually all your results will be in the DB, and your periodic AJAX check to the server which is querying the results will be able to return them to the page. It could wait for all of the calls to the 3 bookstores to finish or it could update the page as and when it gets results back.
6. Your AJAX call updates the page to show the results to the user.

Note if your bookstore doesn't have an API, you might have to consider "web scraping" the results straight from bookstore's website. This is a bit harder and can be quite brittle since web pages obviously change frequently. I have used Geb (http://www.gebish.org/) to automate the browsing along with some simple string matching to pick out things I needed. Also remember to check terms & conditions of the website involved since sometimes scraping is specifically not allowed.

Also note that the above is a server oriented method of accomplishing this kind of thing. You could do it purely on the client (browser), calling out to the webservices using AJAX and processing via JavaScript. But I'm a server man :)

Comment: hey thanks ll try it nys :), can u provide ur mail id so dat can clarify if any doubt

Comment: Haha! I'm not doing your project for you! :) Feel free to ask more questions on stackoverflow and I can respond that way. And please consider upvoting/accepting answer if you think it was helpful :)

Comment: I tried adding {action="http://www.flipkart.com/search/a/books?query="} this link in index.gsp page. It leads it to flipkart site with bookname specified page.but m not able to get how do i compare 3 websites and then lead it to respective sites.

Comment: Try installing the Grails REST Client (http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest) and calling it from the server (i.e. from a controller or service). Experiment with withHttp {...} and withAsyncHttp {...} using your flipkart url. You will have to parse the HTML coming back (looks like Flipkart doesn't have an API).